# How to print specific part of JSON

Tags: python, json, python-requests

I'm requesting JSON data from an URL with `requests.post('url')` and getting output like this

```
{'predictions': [{'fields': ['prediction'], 'values': [[5611.0]]}]}
```

I want to print the specific part of the JSON output:

How to print in Python?

```py
response_scoring = requests.post('http-url', json=payload_scoring, headers={'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + mltoken})
print("Scoring response")
print(response_scoring.json()
```

Output:

```
{'predictions': [{'fields': ['prediction'], 'values': [[5611.0]]}]}
```

How to print `5611.0` only?

Comment: please do not replace existing tutorials. Look up a basic lesson on dictionaries. This is the first thing you learn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try `print(response_scoring.json()['predictions'][0]['values'][0][0])`